# powerdns does not resolve country TLD like .com.au

Tags: powerdns

This is a vague scenario.

I am running a name server using `powerDNS` and adding zones via `poweradmin`.
Somehow it does not resolve .com.au domains and any other for example .co.uk.

Tried trace-route but it says `domain not found in DNS cache`, same with .co.uk, .net.au, etc

However, it resolves .org, .mobi, .net, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to resolve? A record for those? They don't exist.

Comment: .au and .uk is a top level domain (TLD), however .com.au and .co.uk are not.

Comment: You sure you haven't added them to your backend by accident?

Comment: Please use 'dig' directly against your PowerDNS instance to debug resolving issues. 'traceroute' tests far too many things at once.

Comment: @mdpc Yea, sorry... I meant that... @ Habbie it says could not resolve host.

Comment: @cmouse backend by accident? I mean, YES! I have added them and they ar e not resolving, that is the problem

Comment: @Habbie Traceroute lands me to the correct server for all the domains. No glitches! Also, I just noted, when I ping me nameserver with FQDN it does not respond at all however it replies to IP address...

Comment: http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/dns_query.php shows correct results too!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't enough clear and currently I don't have time to check this again, this was the cause why I removed my answer. So you will get better answers with a better chance.

Comment: yea... quite alright... am trying to figure why it wont respond to ping requests..!